# Count max overlapping reservations / bookings of a certain day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

| id | product_id | reserved_from | reserved_till |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-10-30 11:00:00 | 2021-10-30 13:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | **2021-10-28 10:00:00** | 2021-10-28 12:00:00 |
| 3 | 2 | **2021-10-28 11:00:00** | 2021-10-28 13:00:00 |
| 4 | 3 | 2021-10-28 11:00:00 | 2021-10-28 13:00:00 |
| 5 | 2 | 2021-10-28 08:00:00 | 2021-10-28 09:00:00 |
| 6 | 2 | **2021-10-28 12:00:00** | 2021-10-28 16:00:00 |
| 7 | 2 | 2021-10-30 11:00:00 | 2021-10-30 13:00:00 |
| 8 | 2 | 2021-10-28 08:30:00 | 2021-10-28 09:30:00 |

What I want is that I get **3** as maximum counted collisions / overlaps for product_id **2** on date **2021-10-28** (id: 2,3,6 are overlapping and the max).

After researching on Google, I found severall SQL statements, but those are based on start time and end time instead of day instead on finding the maximum collisions on that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-`join`:

```
select count(*) overlap from bookings b join bookings b1 
on b1.product_id = b.product_id and b.id != b1.id and date(b.reserved_from) = date(b.reserved_till) and b1.reserved_till > b.reserved_from and b1.reserved_from < b.reserved_from
where b.product_id = 2 and date(b.reserved_from) = "2021-10-28"
```

Output:

```
overlap
-------
3
```

Comment: Thanks this seems indeed the solution!